# TableViewCelll Reusable Identifier LocationManager

Tags: swift, uitableview, cllocationmanager

I try to display a Distance between two coordinates in an Label inside an TableViewCell, but everytime I scroll, the Data of the Label changes... I know that I need to use Reusable Identifiers, but everything I have tried doesn't work...

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "JobCell", for: indexPath) as! JobTableViewCell
    let job = jobs[indexPath.row]
    cell.job = job
    cell.categorie.text = job.categorie
    cell.distance.text = JobTableViewCell.takenLocation
    return cell
}
```

And I calculate the distance inside the TableViewCell Class

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    if let lastLocation = locations.last {
        let geocoder = CLGeocoder()
        //get job coordinates
        geocoder.geocodeAddressString(job.location) { placemarks, error in
            let placemarkW = placemarks?.first
            if let placemark = placemarkW
            {
                let lat = placemark.location?.coordinate.latitude
                let lon = placemark.location?.coordinate.longitude
                let jobLocation = CLLocation(latitude: lat!, longitude: lon!)
                //get user coordinates
                let myLocation = CLLocation(latitude: lastLocation.coordinate.latitude, longitude: lastLocation.coordinate.longitude)
                //get distance between coordinates
                let distance = myLocation.distance(from: jobLocation) / 1000
                self.distance.text = String(format: "%.01fkm", distance)
                self.job.distance = distance
                JobTableViewCell.takenLocation = String(format: "%.01km", distance)
            } else {
                self.distance.text = "Not Valid"
                self.job.distance = 0.0
                
            }
            self.reloading?.reloadIt()
        }
    }
    self.location.stopUpdatingLocation()
    guard let _: CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location?.coordinate else { return }
}
```

I've heard that not to reuse Cells is a very bad idea, so is there any way to solve my problem? (Btw. the categorie Label works)

EDIT
New Class for Calculation:

```
class CalculateDistance: NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate{

var reloading:Reloading?
let location = CLLocationManager()
var job: Job!
var noDistance: String = ""
static var gettingDistance: String = ""

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    if let lastLocation = locations.last {
        let geocoder = CLGeocoder()
        //get job coordinates
        geocoder.geocodeAddressString(job.location) { placemarks, error in
            let placemarkW = placemarks?.first
            if let placemark = placemarkW
            {
                let lat = placemark.location?.coordinate.latitude
                let lon = placemark.location?.coordinate.longitude
                let jobLocation = CLLocation(latitude: lat!, longitude: lon!)
                //get user coordinates
                let myLocation = CLLocation(latitude: lastLocation.coordinate.latitude, longitude: lastLocation.coordinate.longitude)
                //get distance between coordinates
                let distance = myLocation.distance(from: jobLocation) / 1000
                CalculateDistance.gettingDistance = String(format: "%.01fkm", distance)
            } else {
                self.noDistance = "Not Valid"
            }
            self.reloading?.reloadIt()
        }
    }
    self.location.stopUpdatingLocation()
    guard let _: CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location?.coordinate else { return }
}

}
```

Comment: Your basic problem is that there's only one `takenLocation` shared among all your cells.  When you scroll, `cellForRowAt` gets called for different cells but `takenLocation` is being updated from the async method `geocodeAddressString`.  That means you can't be sure which cell's job was used in the most recent calculation.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a separate class to calculate location. Cell's job is to display UI and interact with user.
2. In your code **geocoder** will provide you **placemarks** on completion, it works async, that means TableView cell will be loaded, but **placemarks** will comes later. Calculate distance and once you get it, call tableView.reloadData() (don't forget to call it in a main queue.

If you need more info, feel free to ask!